Remove one of the fully duplicates from table in snowflake
I have a table in snowflake having couple of duplicate records. For an example lets say I have table customer with the column.

firstname, lastname, age

Here I am able to find a duplicate records by firstname, lastname and age using row number window function. But unable to apply delete DML operation as it seems to be not working in snowflake.
Does anyone know the reason why snowflake doesn't allow using row number along with delete
thanks in advance
I tried using row number windows function to find those duplicates and getting unique numbers in order by firstname, lastname and age, partition by all of the columns (firstname, lastname, age)
Sample records (cant share real data)



firstname
lastname
age




castor
smith
40


castor
smith
40


dakota
justice
32


dakota
justice
32


alice
scott
12


alice
scott
12


jenny
l
23



My current code
with cte (firstname, lastname, age) as
(
select 'castor', 'smith', 40 union all
select 'castor', 'smith', 40 union all
select 'dakota', 'justice', 32 union all
select 'dakota', 'justice', 32 union all
select 'alice', 'scott', 12 union all
select 'alice', 'scott', 12 union all
select 'jenny', 'l', 23
)
select * from cte 
qualify row_number () over (partition by firstname, lastname, age order by firstname, lastname, age) != 1


How could it use row number with delete when row number is ephemeral and only defined in your sql. It's not a value that is intrinsic to the table. You can surface duplicates using that logic, but you will still have to decide which of the two records to delete by specifying the unique identifier for that record in your delete statement. If you share sample data, your current sql that uses row_number logic, and desired results we can probably help you craft that delete statement.

Thanks @JNevill i am wondering how it allows in sql server then. if i recall correctly, i can use row number in cte and then apply delete on that cte specifying derived column filter. i will add some sample data in question

@JNevill sample records and query added. i want to delete the records i am getting in resultset

you may try reloading the data instead of deleting duplicates.
sql => insert overwrite into customer
select distinct * from customer

Thanks @mova any way to delete rather than reloading data?

No other way that I can think of :) @Castor

This question is similar to: How to delete duplicate records in Snowflake database table. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The easiest solution to your problem is this SQL

INSERT OVERWRITE INTO <your_table>
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <your_table>;


You might want to create a backup before just for validation
CREATE TABLE CLN_<your_table> CLONE <tour_table>;


Thanks @demircioglu i see mova is referring to the same solution. do you have any other way rather than refreshing table with distinct rows?

You can create a new table insert distinct into the new table, drop the old table and rename the table. There is not much of a choice here

Not a direct answer to the question, but this might help others:
If you are using Snowpipe (or COPY INTO) to load the data, you can use METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER to differentiate the records.
Duplicates can happen often when using AWS Firehose to load data to S3, because PUT record operations must sometimes be retried (which is the recommended way to handle errors; see documentation here and here):

If there is an internal server error or a timeout, the write might have completed or it might have failed. If FailedPutCount is greater than 0, retry the request, resending only those records that might have failed processing. This minimizes the possible duplicate records and also reduces the total bytes sent (and corresponding charges). We recommend that you handle any duplicates at the destination.

So you might end up with a DELETE query like this:
DELETE FROM my_table AS t
USING (
  SELECT id, file_name, file_row_number
  FROM my_table
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY file_name, file_row_number
  ) > 1
) AS dupes
WHERE t.id = dupes.id
  AND t.file_name = dupes.file_name
  AND t.file_row_number = dupes.file_row_number;


id is the primary/unique key (which could be multiple fields), which is the field(s) against which duplicates are found.
file_name is the METADATA$FILENAME
file_row_number is the METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER.

And once your source data is free of duplicates, there are no more problems dealing with duplicates downstream. At that point, those duplicates could only come from a SQL programming error (usually a bad join), so:

Fix the error.
And then re-run your pipelines.

